# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions'

Tags: python

I have looked into other similar posts, but could not find an answer.

So,

Here is the structure of the project I am working on:

```
lyrics/__init__.py
lyrics/functions.py
manifold.py
```

When I execute *manifold.py* with this command:

```
./manifold.py
```

it calls:

```
import lyrics as lyr
```

which in turn calls **init**.py, which calls:

```
from lyrics import *
import functions
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manifold.py", line 20, in <module>
    import lyrics as lyr
  File "/g../__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import functions
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions'
```

Any idea where the error comes from ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import relatively, you have to add the `.` before functions, i.e. `from . import functions`

The import there works similar to unix: The single dot is for the current directory. If you put two dots (`..`) you go up one level, three dots (`...`) goes up two levels and so on.

If you want to go absolute, then `from lyrics import functions` should work.

Comment: Sorry but this does not work, I get the error:     import .functions SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @RandomFellow I'm sorry, I made a mistake. It should be `from . import functions`. I corrected that.

Comment: function.py file is on the same directory as __init__.py, yet *import .fucntions* does not work, it creates the error: import .functions SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @RandomFellow As the duplicate shows, it should probably be `from . import functions`